# What are some references to Mathonwy in Welsh legends?

Tags: comparative, welsh, source-request, reference-request, european-folklore

Mathonwy is the father of [Math fab Mathony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_fab_Mathonwy) and a mother godess [Dôn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%B4n) in Welsh legend, who is believed to be analogous to Danu from [Irish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danu_(Irish_goddess)) and [Vedic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danu_(Asura)) legends.

Are there any surviving sources, either direct or references from the medieval era, pertaining to Mathonwy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, I've never been able to find any direct references to Mathonwy anywhere.

[Bromwich](https://books.google.com/books/about/Trioedd_ynys_Prydein.html?id=m5piAAAAMAAJ) (pg. 439) mentions that the name Mathonwy itself could be a doublet for the name Math, like so many names in *Culhwch ac Olwen* are.  If so, Mathonwy may never have represented a specific character.

One final thing worth mentioning is that it's unclear whether Mathonwy was Math's father or mother, as the form of the name could be appropriate for either a male or female.  Additionally, the *Mabinogi* suggests Math may have belonged to a matrilinear descent line. 
Again, Bromwich points out that Math "is succeeded by the sister’s son (Lleu) of his sister’s son (Gwydion). In these circumstances a matronymic might be expected, such as in fact we find that Gwydion receives: he is known invariably as *vab Dôn*."